# Add value to each 100 entries in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the table "tweets" with the thousands of entries. I want to divide these into blocks of 100 to be processed in turn, whilst keeping them within the one table.

Hopefully by the end of this, I'll have an extra column "group_ID" with 100 entries where it is "1", 100 where it is "2" and so on.

To provide a little more context: I've got somewhere in the region of 10,000 sample tweets. I want to divide these into groups of 100. Each group will be released to the public to be tagged. When I have enough data for these tweets, I'll release group number 2... and so on...

I'm looking for a way to give set the column `group_ID` within the database itself. Entirely at random, I want there to be 100 where it is set to `1`, 100 where it is set to `2` and so on.

(Apologies for being a little unclear earlier on!)

Comment: Why are you doing this and what's your question?

Comment: I'm getting a load of humans to tag a group of tweets. Since I'm relying on humans to tag the tweets, I want them to be divided into chunks that can be tagged completely before I move on to the next block of 100 tweets.

I've added more context to the bottom of the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a pagination behavior, like show entry 1 to 100 in one page, 101 to 200 in the next and so on, the `LIMIT` clause will help.

Assuming your table is called `SAMPLE` and you need to display entries 1 to 100, the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE LIMIT 0,100;
```

You can test this behavior in this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9204/1

Comment: I'm trying to do it in the Database - so that I can release each group individually (allowing me to get the data for each block of 100 tweets in turn). 

In this case - it simply shows me 100 random tweets, rather than dividing them into groups. I've edited this into the main question to make it a little clearer.